# Intel HD 4600: No 3D support

Tags: unity, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics, 3d

I've got an MSI GE-40 laptop with an Intel HD 4600 (integrated in Core i7-4702MQ CPU) and GeForce GTX760M GPU running Ubuntu 13.10. It looks like 3D is not supported:

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
OpenGL vendor string:   VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.3, 256 bits)
OpenGL version string:  2.1 Mesa 9.2.1

Not software rendered:    no
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       no
```

I've run glmark2 and it gets a score of 144.

1. Am I right that 3D is not working (but is being rendered by the CPU instead)?
2. What can I do to have the Intel GPU support 3D or switch to the NVIDIA GPU?

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if you need more information.

```
sudo lshw -C video
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: 3D controller
       product: GK106M [GeForce GTX 760M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the problem. During the installation I had to add the `nomodeset` kernel parameter. Removing this parameter from `/etc/default/grub` and running `update-grub` solved the issue. Now the correct driver is being loaded.